# How to close side menu when the dark area is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built a simple side navigation. If you run the snippet and resize the window to smaller size you'll see a red square. If you click on it, the menu opens.

The menu opens fine, however I'd like to close the menu when I click the dark area, not the X. I tried adding a "click" eventListener to the body itself and remove the "is-open" class but didn't work. I spent several hours thinking what could be the problem and finally decided to post here and ask for your suggestion.

```js
"use strict";

const menuToggle = document.querySelector(".menu-toggle");
const menuClose = document.querySelector(".menu-close");
const nav = menuToggle.parentElement;

menuToggle.addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  nav.classList.add("is-open");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
});

menuClose.addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  menuToggle.nextElementSibling.style.width = null;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = null;
  nav.classList.remove("is-open");
});
```

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-toggle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-container {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightskyblue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
}

.nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.nav-menu > li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nav-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


.nav.is-open .menu-container {
  width: 200px;
}

.menu-close::before {
  content: "\00d7";
  font-size: 2.6rem;
}

/*@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {*/
@media screen and (min-width: 40.5em) {
  body {
    background: #fff !important;
  }

  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav.is-open .menu-container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }

  .menu-container {
    position: initial;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;

  }

  .menu-close {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    position: static;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .nav-menu > li {
    margin-left: 1em;
  }

  .nav-menu > li + li {
    border-top: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hamburgerside.css">
  <title>Hamburger Menu Side</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="menu-toggle">
    <span class="menu-toggle__linecenter"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-container">
    <span class="menu-close"></span>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<main>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Accusamus accusantium aliquid consequatur facere illum
    incidunt magnam magni maiores nam neque numquam omnis
    perferendis porro quae quibusdam, quos sed tenetur ullam.
  </p>
</main>
<script src="hamburgerside.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried copying and pasting your code into codepen and its not working at all, can you post a working code pen of your code? Then I think i can help you  https://codepen.io/

Comment: https://codepen.io/zoliky/pen/povOrpj

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Seems that you want it to function like a modal where the background goes dark and if you click there the menu is hidden? menu-toggle is hidden because of your media query and not seeing the effect (dark area) of your click event.

Comment: Yes, just like a modal. menu-toggle is only used to open the menu, I don't need it after the menu opens, since I use the X to close. I'll change the name toggle. However I'd like the menu to be closed when clicking the dark area as well.

Comment: nothing happens when I click a menu item on the code pen :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want, I added a new div next to the menu with a class `hidden` and for the script when the `event.target` is equal to that div or the close button then will fire the function. check it out and let me know if you have any questions.

```js
const menuToggle = document.querySelector(".menu-toggle");
const menuClose = document.querySelector(".menu-close");
const menuActive = document.querySelector(".menu_active");
const nav = menuToggle.parentElement;

const log = console.log;

const app = {
  init: () => {
    app.menuToggle();
  },

  menuToggle: () => {
    menuToggle.addEventListener("click", event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      nav.classList.add("is-open");
      menuActive.classList.remove('hidden');
      app.closeMenu();
    });
    log('working')

  },
  closeMenu: () => {
    if (nav.classList.contains('is-open')) {

      document.addEventListener("click", event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let closeMenu = event.target.className;
        if (closeMenu === 'menu_active' || closeMenu === 'menu-close') {
          //log(event.target.className)
          menuToggle.nextElementSibling.style.width = null;
          menuActive.classList.add('hidden');
          nav.classList.remove("is-open");
        }
      });
    }
  }

};


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', app.init())
```

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu_active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100vw - 200px);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.menu-toggle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-container {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightskyblue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
}

.nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.nav-menu>li+li {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nav-menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav.is-open .menu-container {
  width: 200px;
}

.menu-close::before {
  content: "\00d7";
  font-size: 2.6rem;
}


/*@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {*/

@media screen and (min-width: 40.5em) {
  body {
    background: #fff !important;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav.is-open .menu-container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  .menu-container {
    position: initial;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .menu-close {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    position: static;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-menu>li {
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
  .nav-menu>li+li {
    border-top: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="nav">
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <span class="menu-toggle__linecenter"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-container">
      <span class="menu-close"></span>
      <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_active hidden"></div>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus accusantium aliquid consequatur facere illum incidunt magnam magni maiores nam neque numquam omnis perferendis porro quae quibusdam, quos sed tenetur ullam.
    </p>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. I like your solution. It's neat. I removed the `width: calc(100vw - 200px);` and replaced it with `width: 100%;` then set `z-index: 1` on `.menu-container`, this removes that ugly white on the left when the menu opens.

Comment: There is one more issue, when the menu is open and you stretch the window out (while the menu stays open), the dark background is still there. I want it to dissapear but when returning to reappear. I'm not sure if you get the idea. Here's a video in which it works as I want it to be: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ko3keTNUjdk  I was able to do that by setting a `display: none` on the `.menu_active` in the media query. What do you think about my solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a toggle, that class name is erronous, .toggle-menu only opens the menu and that's all it does. So, I need to have the event listener attached to the document regardless of `if (nav.classList.contains('is-open')) {` is true or not.

Comment: @ZoltanKing yeah you can do that `display: none;` in the media query, unfortunately I couldn't see the video you added. I see what you're saying you can change that class name (burger_menu) for example, and add the `eventListener` to the document and get `e.target` is = to  `burger_menu` and contains class of `is-open` then fire function to close it and remove the class, else you fire a function to open it and add class `is-open`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you will need to use `document` rather than `body` for the click event. You will also need to use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` rather than `event.preventDefault()` which will allow the first click but not the second. Also in the condition you would need to only run the click event if anywhere but the menu is clicked.

NOTE: I had to remove your media query as it was preventing the toggle-menu from being displayed.

```js
"use strict";

const menuToggle = document.querySelector(".menu-toggle");
const menuClose = document.querySelector(".menu-close");
const nav = menuToggle.parentElement;

menuToggle.addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  
  nav.classList.add("is-open");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.5)";
});

document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  if (nav.classList.contains("is-open") && !event.target.classList.contains("nav-menu")) {
    menuToggle.nextElementSibling.style.width = null;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    nav.classList.remove("is-open");
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-toggle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-container {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightskyblue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
}

.nav-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.nav-menu > li + li {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nav-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


.nav.is-open .menu-container {
  width: 200px;
}

.menu-close::before {
  content: "\00d7";
  font-size: 2.6rem;
}

}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="menu-toggle">
    <span class="menu-toggle__linecenter"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-container">
    <span class="menu-close"></span>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<main>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Accusamus accusantium aliquid consequatur facere illum
    incidunt magnam magni maiores nam neque numquam omnis
    perferendis porro quae quibusdam, quos sed tenetur ullam.
  </p>
</main>
```

Comment: The red square (menu-toggle) is not a toggle icon. I used the wrong class name, sorry for the confusion. It just opens the menu, that's all it does. The menu gets closed by the X mark or by clicking on the dark area. "event.stopImmediatePropagation()" was the culprit, after adding it everything works fine. Wow! thanks! I put a console.log inside the event listener for debugging only and I noticed it fires every time I click on the body regardless if the menu is open or not. It makes sense, the event is on document but can that be a problem performance-wise?

Comment: The condition doesn't work. Problem is, you can prevent execution on a specific element but still trying to work out preventing it for all the children/grandchildren.

Comment: @ZoltanKing the reason for using document is because the body may not fill the entire screen/window.